# Pass variable from Jenkins to Ruby script (Jenkins newbie)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, jenkins, watir, watir-webdriver

I've pulled a few scripts into Jenkins for a proof of concept and think I'd like to move that direction for all of our scripts.  Right now I keep an environment.rb file with my code (watir-webdriver, cucumber) which tells the script which environment we're testing and which browser to use (global variables).  Jenkins fires off the script using rake.

I'd love to let the user choose the environment and browser through Jenkins 'choice' variable or similar, and then pass that to the script.  While I see the framework in that for Jenkins and set up a choice list for environment, I'm having trouble determining what the next step is.

I could write to environment.rb, I could pass a variable to rake - I have many options for how to pass the information, I just need some assistance finding the first step to find the Jenkins way of accomplishing them.  Google results and previous Stack questions weren't what I was looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Give the user either a text entry field a dropdown after telling Jenkins that this is a parameterized build. You'll give them a name, something like BuildEnvironment. Then when you call the build, you can pass these from the environment variables. For example, if you were using ANT, you'd add a line to the parameters that said environment = ${MyEnvironment} Jenkins will then pass the value along for your build tool to use.

Comment: So for a 'choice' environment variable called Environment, with options QA, Dev and Production, and a single build task that invokes rake:  Where would the Environment variable be passed?  Or is the value already available to rake? ENV['Envinronment']?

Comment: Looks like it is already available as ENV['variablename'].  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to pass Jenkins Environment Variable to Ruby script. Please see the following example:

```
workspace_path = `echo $WORKSPACE`.strip # note the use of backticks
puts workspace_path
```

In the "echo $WORKSPACE".strip # the code work only if you **replace quotes with backticks**

This code example works in Jenkins on a Linux system.